# Settlement visa for UK

Tags: visas, uk, residency

If you send your documents to Sheffield, they send them back, saying that you are supposed to resend them to the decisionmaker.

I sent them to my country, but they refused to accept them. They said the documents were supposed to be submitted on the same day that my wife and my son applied.

What can I do now, because the application doesn't have any supporting documents? My wife's and my son's passports are at the Visa Application Centre already. I have my documents with me and I don't know where to send them. I paid everything already, the visa and NHS fees.